# RobotFramework DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: database, robotframework

Hi I am currently doing an automation testing script. And I have a portion where I would like to extract the data from the database and input them in text-fields.

This is how I have written my codes:

```
Retrieve and Input
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    cx_Oracle    '${Database Username}/${Database Password}@${Database Host}:${Database Port}/${DatabaseName}'
${ETD_Day}=      Execute Sql String      SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM 'DECL_UNBTHG_DT') FROM BAS_BERTH_APPLN_MASTER WHERE ABBR_VSL_M='APL';
Input Text      ${FlexiStack_Day}       ${ETD_Day}
Disconnect From Database
```

However when I am running for testing, this error showed up when trying to execute the sql string.

> DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character

I have tried to run the SQL statement in SQL developer and it works. May I know what is the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried an example with all the variables replaced by their actual values? I.e. hard coding them?

Comment: Hi @A.Kootstra, thanks for the reply, but I dont think trying a hard coded example will solve the problem I am facing... my main focus to the extract the value from database...

Comment: The reason I'm asking for it is because it's an additional complexity and I think the example should be as simple as possible. If the text works fine in SQL Developer, then have a look at the Robot Script file encoding. If this is different from what the connection expects, it may cause a similar issue.

Comment: If the SQL text has a trailing semi-colon, remove it.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks alot! It works now, but the value being retrieved is 'None'... any idea why?

Comment: You'll need to share more information about the table and python code for anyone to help further.